# How to configure ElasticBeanstalk to store access logs for classic ELB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, terraform, elastic-load-balancer

I'm using Terraform to provision ElasticBeanstalk application.
EC2 instances are placed into auto scaling group and accessed via (classic) Elastic Load Balancer.

Now I need to store access the logs to that load balancer in S3.
I see it is possible to do manually from web console (EC2/Load Balancers/Description/Attributes/Access logs). Also Terraform allows to configure access logs for aws_elb (if it is created not by ElasticBeanstalk).
However, ElasticBeanstalk does not allow to configure access logs for classic load balancer ([see docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/command-options-general.html?shortFooter=true#command-options-general-elbloadbalancer)) only for application load balancer.

So the question is: how can I configure ElasticBeanstalk to store access logs for **classic load balancer**?

I realize that I can change the balancer type but I'd like to avoid that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by creating an `.ebextensions` directory in the root of your deployment bundle, and saving a configuration file there. Here's the file that we use, which configures the ELB to save logs every 5 minutes:

```
Resources:
  AWSEBLoadBalancer:
    Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancing::LoadBalancer
    Properties:
      AccessLoggingPolicy:
        EmitInterval: 5
        Enabled: true
        S3BucketName: "example-elb-logs"
        S3BucketPrefix: { "Fn::Sub" : "example/${AWSEBEnvironmentName}" }
```

If you're thinking "this looks a lot like a CloudFormation template" you're right: Beanstalk adds the fragments in this directory to its base template.

For more information on `.ebextensions`: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/ebextensions.html